# How to count files using recursion method?

Tags: python, recursion

I want to write a method to count the number of files in a specific path and if this path contains folders the method calls itself recursively to count the files inside the child folder, the problem is when the folder belongs to the operating system does not allow a method to count files like the root folder How do I avoid these folders.

```
import os
def dirNum(drive):
    dirCount=0
    for arr in os.listdir(drive):
        if  os.path.isdir(drive+"/"+arr) :
            dirCount+=dirNum(drive+"/"+arr)
    return dirCount
       
dirc=dirNum("d:/")
print(f"dirs={dirc} ")
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Programming/Python/lessons/firstLesson.py", line 11, in <module>
    dirc=dirNum("d:/")
  File "d:/Programming/Python/lessons/firstLesson.py", line 7, in dirNum
    dirCount+=dirNum(drive+"/"+arr)
  File "d:/Programming/Python/lessons/firstLesson.py", line 5, in dirNum
    for arr in os.listdir(drive):
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'd://System Volume Information'
```

Comment: Ask if what is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend looking at [os.walk()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm).

The error is a permission error... ie. you can't access some dirs.

Also, seems the error occurred on Windows... recommend os.path.join().

```
import os
def dirNum(drive):
    dirCount=0
    try: fList = os.listdir(drive)
    except Exception as err:
        print("ERROR on ", drive, err)
        return 0

    for p in fList:
        fn = os.path.join(drive, p)
        try:            
            if  os.path.isdir(fn):
                dirCount+=dirNum(fn)
        except Exception as err:
            print("ERROR on ", fn, err)
    return dirCount

dirc=dirNum("d:/")
print(f"dirs={dirc} ")
```